# Getting RowIndex based on the multiple selected cells on a DataGridGiew

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to get the row indices based on my multiple selected cells on a DataGridView. How can I do that in VB.NET?

This is what I have:

```
If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    sno.Text = row.Cells("F2").Value.ToString
    sname.Text = row.Cells("F3").Value.ToString
    final.Text = row.Cells("F16").Value.ToString
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

DatagridView has a SelectedCells propertry and a RowIndex on each cell:

```
    For Each c As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
        Debug.Print(c.RowIndex)
    Next
```

You will get a hit for each selected cell - possibly with duplicate rRowIndex.

You can set the SelectionMode to rows and use SelectedRows.

---

To use the first selected cell as the row to use:

```
If DataGridView1.SelectedCells.count > 0 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex)
    sno.Text = row.Cells("F2").Value.ToString
    sname.Text = row.Cells("F3").Value.ToString
    final.Text = row.Cells("F16").Value.ToString
End If
```

Comment: 2nd option may not work - I think the .Selected... methods may not return the cells/rows in a defined order i.e. the last Cell may be the 0th cell.